# myeclipse deployment issue cant see changes

Tags: apache, tomcat, myeclipse

Im trying to work in my project, when I change files it changes the file inside the directory that I imported the projects into my workspace. But the changes aren't showing up on the server because the server is using the folder inside .metadata/webapps/myapp etc

what have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're deploying to the integrated Tomcat server. The deployment is normally to the .metadata/.me_tcat/webapps/myapp folder. Is this what you meant? If not then I suggest you remove the deployment and then deploy again and let the deployment location default. The folder .metadata/.me_tcap is simply where the integrated Tomcat installation looks for applications when it starts up.

You can check the deployment location by looking in the servers view. Expand the integrated Tomcat server. The deployment location for your project is shown there.

The deployed location should be kept in synch with your code. If that's not happening, it may be that the changes you're making are the kind that require a redeployment. I'm not sure what the conditions are for propagating changes but I guess there might be some situations where changes can't be picked up automatically in this way. The changes should be picked up on a redeploy.

To check, create a new web project, which will create some default configuration and a default index.jsp file. Deploy this to the integrated Tomcat server. Now make a change in the index.jsp file and save it. Check if the change is made in the deployment location, or simply run the server and check that your new index.jsp gets displayed.

For more help, I suggest you post to the forums at www.myeclipseide.com/forums